# Generate a list of directories that the user has access to

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application which generates a HTML replica of folders on a network drive. I'm using

```
Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

To enumerate the folders and repeating that for each sub folder to build a complete tree.

```
string[] subFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
foreach (string folder in subFolders)
{
       // Load sub folders          
}
```

This works fine, however the code is running on a web server in a user account which has access to all folders on the network drive.

What is the most efficient way to limit the directory tree to only show folders that a given user has windows permission to access? To test access to each folder individually seems inefficient.

I do not have the users windows passwords only their usernames. I would like to be able to draw the tree as "UserA" then redraw the tree as "UserB" etc by passing in a different username.

Comment: If you don’t have the password then you can’t impersonate the user, and if you can’t impersonate then checking folder permissions is the only way. If permissions don’t change you can do it as a background process?

Comment: @stuartd even if they changed, a scheduled task to review/update the folder permissions could be done

Comment: A scheduled task to create a cached table would be acceptable but how do I test a specific user has access to a specific folder using only their username?